# Google Directions API preferred transit mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps website provides the option to specify a preferred transit mode -- under "Show options" after selecting "by public transit" -- when requesting transit directions. Is there a way to pass this parameter to the Google Maps API Directions service? There also exists the option to prefer fewer transfers or less walking. However, I find no mention of these parameters in the API documentation.

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding clarification in a comment to one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+cityStart+"&destination="+cityEnd+"&transit_mode="+transitMode+"&key=YOUR_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%22+cityStart+%22&destination=%22+cityEnd+%22&transit_mode=%22+transitMode+%22&key=YOUR_KEY)

for transit_mode u can use any rail of train or of this here :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#transit_mode

and for less walking u can set transit_routing_preference to less_walking or fewer_transfers. here you can find more details:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#transit_routing_preference

Answer (score 0):

I think you've flown over the "mode" optional parameter in documentation :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes

;-)

Comment: Apologies for being unclear - I meant the transit mode that's available under "Show options" on the Google Maps website after selecting "by public transit" (i.e., "Any transit mode", "Bus", "Subway", "Train", or "Train / Light rail"). There also exists the option to prefer fewer transfers or less walking. However, I find no mention of these parameters in the API documentation.